# Can I select a subset of predictor variables without using step()?

Tags: multiple-regression, feature-selection

I have a set of 20 predictor variables, and I want to formulate a regression model by applying my own variable selection technique basically with backward approach (just for an experiment purpose.)

I'm rather new to `R`, and as far as I have studied so far, if I were to do it automatically I would use `step()` like this:

```
y2y <- read.csv(my CSV location)
y2y.lm <- lm(myTarget~., data=y2y)
y2y.step <- step(y2y.lm)
```

However, I'd like to apply my own technique to select variables using the calculation results based on p-values, and so far I have figured out that I can obtain the largest p-value and the corresponding variable name by

```
maxV <- which.max(summary.lm(y2y.lm)$coefficients[,"Pr(>|t|)"])
maxV
attr(maxV,"names")
```

If I do the calculation repeatedly (and stepwise) in a loop until a condition is met, using `for()` or `while()`, then I can probably achieve my goal.
However, I just can't figure out the way to formulate the model dynamically to feed to `lm()` in the loop, e.g.

`myTarget ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4.....`

using the set of variables I selected.
For instance, in the first loop, if `x2` was selected as a variable to drop, I want the equation to look like

`myTarget ~ x1 + x3 + x4.....`

Is there a way to dynamically formulate the equation to feed to `lm()`?

I'd appreciate your suggestions and insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Example Data
y = rnorm(100)
x1 = rnorm(100,5)
x2 = rnorm(100,3)
x3 = rnorm(100,8)
x4 = rnorm(100,18)
x5 = rnorm(100,100)
x6 = rnorm(100,100)
x7 = rnorm(100,100)
x8 = rnorm(100,100)
x9 = rnorm(100,100)

#Put the covariates into a matrix
X = data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9)

#Fit the full model
model = lm(y~.,data=X)

#N is the number of covariates to remove one at a time
#based on p-values
N = 5

for(i in 1:N){
    remove = which.max(summary(model)$coefficients[2:ncol(X),4])
    X = X[,-remove]

    model = lm(y~.,data=X)

    #Uncomment to see that the right p-values were removed
    #print(summary(model))

}
```

Comment: No problem. Good luck!